# Underline small-capped section with titleformat?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, article, small-caps

With the MWE in place, i got the smallcaps into the section formatting (hopefully right), but cannot use `\titleformat` to uline the section, despite the doc saying: ["The very last command can take an argument,
which is the title text."](http://%22The%20very%20last%20command%20can%20take%20an%20argument,%20which%20is%20the%20title%20text.%22) but the `uline` is ignored. Furthermore it shouldnt have numbering. Just an underlined small-caps section.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[pdftex, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}%bad w/ small-caps
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 

\titleformat{\section}{\vspace{-0pt}\scshape}{}{0pt}{\uline{#1}}[\vspace{-5pt}]
\let\resumeSection\section

\begin{document} 
%---------------------OBJECTIVE
\resumeSection{Objective}
blue blue
\end{document}
%FIN
```

The error at each `\resumeSection` is

> ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal
>   mode.  @empty ##
>                        1\xdef \UL@spfactor {\the \spacefactor }

solved:
[image: solved]

Comment: According to the manual, without using the package option `explicit` the last command is assumed to have an argument without the need of typing `#1` explicitly. Just replace `\uline{#1}` by `\uline`.

Comment: this actually solves it :)